Any way to send to an android phone a notification with an attached picture uploaded from local directory?
I have a picture that is regularly updated by my local server. I would need a tool to send a regular notification on my android phone that I can trigger from my local raspberry pi 4 server and receive on my android device.
Closest I got was using ntfy. This is the request that I send :
user1@raspberrypi:~/Documents $ curl     -F "data=@test.png" ntfy.sh/test1 -H "file: test.png" 
{"id":"pY7J512zoZcf","time":1715963805,"expires":1716007005,"event":"message","topic":"test1","message":"You received a file: test.png","attachment":{"name":"test.png","type":"application/octet-stream","size":7210,"expires":1715974605,"url":"https://ntfy.sh/file/pY7J512zoZcf.bin"}}

With this I could indeed receive a notification with the file test.png to download. It is 7kb, which is the good size. But impossible to open on my android device as if it was corrupted.
Tried with a jpg file, same issue.
I could read that it was possible to do so with ntfy if you upload the picture somewhere publicly accessible (see dog example here : https://docs.ntfy.sh/publish/), but I would rather avoid this as it seems like a lot of hassle when I feel like I could just send the picture from my server to my phone.
Any idea how I could proceed? I am also open to ntfy alternatives. I just need it handy from a command line to automate it.
Thank you!

Not clear if you expect the msg to arrive via SMS (and similar) or direct via a internet connection. Assuming SMS, do you know about echo "my message" | mail 555-987-6543@txt.att.net (and similar). Each cell provider has their own domain that accepts messages via number and forwards them to the users cell phone. As cell phones also accept .jpg and other image files, I'm guessing there is a way to wrap that as a mime msg , attaching the file to the message, and then sending that. It shouldn't be too hard to reseach. Start with echo msg | mail ... and get that to work first.

Easiest "quick and dirty" way would probably be a Telegram bot - you can POST messages to an API and receive the message with your regular telegram client.

Using a webhook on discord is free, easy and reliable way of achieving this, see post :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780719/python3-send-a-image-png-into-a-discord-channel-using-webhook/76675692?noredirect=1#comment139119710_76675692
I then execute regularly the python script with a cron job.
